# php get youtube user subscription channel videos

Tags: php, arrays, youtube-api, youtube-channels

how can i use php to get youtube user subscription channel videos and display all the channel feeds, i want create a class or function where if i pass a user name the php class would retrieve the latest uploads / activities in the user subscribed channels  and display the url plus the title and the image, also i want to be able to pass the title and url to other functions so that i can save it to database. on a another page i found this [Pulling in YouTube Videos from Specific Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510128/pulling-in-youtube-videos-from-specific-channel) but its for only one specific channel.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant requests are for the [newsubscriptionvideos feed](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_subscriptions#Retrieving_new_subscription_videos) in the YouTube GData API v2 or [activities.list()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) in the newer YouTube Data API v3.

`newsubscriptionvideos` might not be natively support in the [Zend GData client library](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest) (I don't see it mentioned in [the developer's guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php)), so if you go that route, you should probably use `alt=jsonc` to get back an easy-to-parse JSON feed of the data. E.g, https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/jeffposnicktest/newsubscriptionvideos?v=2&alt=jsonc

The alternative is to use v3's [PHP client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) to call `activities.list()`.